# Excludes library from Search configuration in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api

How to excludes more then one library from Search results in SharePoint 2013 on-premise?

Answer (score 1):

Create crawl rules to exclude specific paths (libraries) when crawling content.

1. Open Central Administration -> Application Management -> Manage Service Applications -> Search Service Application.
2. On the  Search Administration page, click **Crawl Rules**.
3. Click **New Crawl Rule**. In the Crawl Configuration, select **Exclude**.

Useful link: [Manage crawl rules in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj871676.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent a library from being searched in the Site's Administration:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-content-on-a-site-to-be-searchable-2a420d01-4706-4d23-980e-c4c877113670#__toc356211702

Comment: Thanks this is working. But if I want to exclude more library from different sub sites any other alternatives?